# Insert Date and Time only if > = Current Date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, getdate, sql-date-functions

I have a field `appointment_date` and `appointment_time` and datatype is `date` and `time` respectively. The table name is `appointment`. What our teacher wanted was to be able to add appointment ONLY if it is greater than or equal to the `current_date` or `current_time`. I am quite confused with how `getdate()`, `sysdate()`, `dateadd()` or any DATE functions work. Hope you can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to write a trigger for tis.  Have you learned about those?

Comment: Yes, we've touched on triggers. I am mostly confused with the syntax in MySQL. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting lost with time/date functions, there is great documentation with MySQL on the net, check it out here : [Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Given the fact that MySQL doesn't have a conditional INSERT statement, I would advise doing all sorts of checks on the values you want to insert before doing a simple insert without conditional check.

Comment: The syntax `:varName` is JCBD Template' syntax, it stads for the values you're trying to assign. This should be adapted to the way you are actually inserting values into youre SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How do you insert these in MySQL if you don't mind?

Comment: In mysql the on clause can only have `on duplicate key update`, you cannot do such checks there.

Comment: Yep, you're totally right. That completely voids my suggestion. Back to investigation!

Comment: Well the thing is, from what I see in my everyday work, we do that kind of check BEFORE doing the insert. The reason being, I guess, that MySQL doesn't really have a conditional INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

In sql you could enforce such logic using a [check constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint), unfortunately, mysql does not implement this type of constraint just yet. This means, that you either have to check the condition in the application itself before calling an insert statement or you have to create [a stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) to achieve the expected results.

In both solution the logic is simple: with an if conditional statement you check if the value you would like to insert is larger than current date or time (it is actually quite important to which you compare it to).

The 3rd solution is to create a before insert trigger and raise an sql error message from it with [signal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) to prevent the insertion of the record.

Comment: Okay. I will try your suggestions. Thanks :) I'm kinda new to this thing.